# Using sniffing with python elasticsearch client to solve dead TCP connection issues

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack

The Python elasticsearch client in my applicaiton is having connectivity issues (refused connections) because idle TCP connections timeout due to a firewall (I have no way to prevent this).

The easiest way for me to fix this would be if I could prevent the connection from going idle by sending some data over it periodically, the sniffing options in the elasticsearch client seem ideal for this, however they're [not very well documented](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/connection.html#elasticsearch.Transport):

> sniff_on_start – flag indicating whether to obtain a list of nodes
>   from the cluser at startup time
>
> sniffer_timeout – number of seconds
>   between automatic sniffs
>
> sniff_on_connection_fail – flag controlling
>   if connection failure triggers a sniff
>
> sniff_timeout – timeout used for the sniff request - it should be a fast api call and we are talking potentially to more nodes so we want to fail quickly. Not used during initial sniffing (if sniff_on_start is on) when the connection still isn’t initialized.

What I would like is for the client to sniff every (say) 5 minutes, should I be using the `sniff_timeout` or `sniffer_timeout` option? Also, should the `sniff_on_start` parameter be set to `True`?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640200/elasticsearch-python-client-work-with-many-nodes-how-to-work-with-sniffer/39640389#39640389

Comment: @val I used the settings from that answer and will report back if it works. Takes some time to test this.

Comment: @val it worked! thanks - I've left an answer to this in case other people have this problem.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if it helped ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the suggestion from [@val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val) and found that these settings solved my problem:

```
sniff_on_start=True
sniffer_timeout=60
sniff_on_connection_fail=True
```

The sniffing puts enough traffic on the TCP connections so that they are never idle for long enough for our firewall to kill the conneciton.